# Arranging $3$ red balls, $2$ blue balls, and $2$ green balls so that no two adjacent balls are of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to arrange $3$ red balls, $2$ blue balls, and $2$ green balls in a line so that no two balls of the same color are adjacent. If there are no such restrictions, then the number of such unique arrangements is

$$\frac{7!}{3!\times 2!\times 2!}=210.$$

I found a related problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494758/arranging-30-balls-of-3-colors-such-that-no-2-balls-of-the-same-color-are-togeth) but it does not have an answer. Instead, [I wrote a code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094378/arranging-3-red-balls-2-blue-balls-and-2-green-balls-so-that-no-two-adjacent-b) in R that will completely list all such possible arrangements. I found 38. I also tried to list them manually below.

- _ B _ G _ B _ G _: $C^5_3=10$ arrangements
- _ G _ B _ G _ B _: $C^5_3=10$ arrangements
- _ G R G _ B R B _: 3 arrangements
- _ B R B _ G R G _: 3 arrangements
- _ G _ B R B _ G _: $C^4_2=6$ arrangements
- _ B _ G R G _ B _: $C^4_2=6$ arrangements

Is this correct? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $10$ ways to arrange the red balls. Of these:

1. two arrangements leave three adjacent free spots and one solo free spot:
   $$
   R\,\_\,\_\,\_R\,\_R\\
   R\,\_R\,\_\,\_\,\_R
   $$For each of these: Whichever colour is in the middle of the three free spots must also be in the solo spot, so 2 possibilities for each of these arrangements
2. six arrangements leave two adjacent spots and two solo spots:
   $$
   \,\_\,\_R\,\_R\,\_R\\
   \,\_R\,\_\,\_R\,\_R\\
   \,\_R\,\_R\,\_\,\_R\\
   R\,\_\,\_R\,\_R\,\_\\
   R\,\_R\,\_\,\_R\,\_\\
   R\,\_R\,\_R\,\_\,\_
   $$ 
   and one leaves two pairs of adjacent spots:
   $$
   R\,\_\,\_R\,\_\,\_R
   $$For each of these: the colours must differ in a pair of adjacent spots, but they can be swapped around, so 4 possibilities for each of these arrangements
3. one arrangement leaves no adjacent spots: 
   $$
   \,\_R\,\_R\,\_R\,\_
   $$
   Here there are six possible arrangements of the remaining $4$ balls

In total:
$$
2\cdot 2 + 7\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 6 = 38
$$
I don't think there is a more "elegant" way to do this than simply splitting into cases and count. The interactions are too complicated to make inclusion-exclusion viable, and there isn't a simple formula for "non-adjacent" that we can apply. Of course, how you decide to split into cases changes how easy the calculations are and how easily you miss a case or double count.

Comment: Case 3 has only six arrangements of the remaining 4 balls, so your solution agrees with the original poster's.

Comment: @Michael You're right.

Comment: This is a more systematic approach. Indeed, I think it is easier to miss or duplicate cases in my "manual" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might find applying inclusion-exclusion more "elegant"

Keeping the A's apart throughout, count the # of arrangements with

(A's apart) - (A's apart, B's or C's bunched)   + (A's apart, both B's and C's bunched)

$ = \left[\frac{4!}{2!2!}\times \binom53 \right] - \left[2\times \frac{3!}{2!}\binom43\right] + \left[2!\times\binom33\right] = 60 - 2\cdot12 + 2 =38$

Comment: Definitely is! Thanks for taking your time to answer this. So insightful.

Comment: You are welcome !